# Using Textbox Value to set iframe src

Tags: html, iframe, textbox, src

Is it possible to have an HTML `<iframe>` with a textbox that sets the `src` element of the iframe?. It would kind of be like a browser within a browser

Comment: In theory. But any interactions between document and iframe very limited. You can try messages http://javascript.info/tutorial/cross-window-messaging-with-postmessage

Comment: How would you use the code on that site for this purpose?